# Constraints across related dependent variables

Tags: regression, logistic, python, ordered-logit

I'm working on model that uses a set of features like `track_type`, `driver_age` and some lag variables to predict the number of `laps_in_first_place` for each car in a stock car race.

`laps_in_first_place` ~ `track_type` + `driver_age` (...)

I assembled my data and started with a few different regression models (linear, random forest, SVM) which produced a decent cross validation score, but there is a problem:

For a race with **100 laps total**, I would hope the sum of `laps_in_first_place` for all drivers in a single race would **equal 100**, since there are 100 laps total and someone has to be in the lead for each of them. It turns out that **the sums my models spit out are not exactly 100**.

Are there models/modeling strategies to impose constraints on a group of dependent variables? (in my case, ensure the sum of all `laps_in_first_place` for drivers in a race equal the total number of laps)